# Return value from local scope?

Tags: c++, c

Bumped into some code like this in our code base... which made me worried.

```
int foo(int a); // Forward declaration.

int baz() {
    int result = {
         int a = dosomestuff();
         foo(a);
    } ? 0 : -1;
    return result;
}
```

1. Is the behavior of this code well-defined?
2. Will it really work, that `result` variable gets loaded with 0 or -1 depending on the return value of `foo(a)`?

---

For interest: The code was not written like that originally - however, it is what I imagine this innocent-looking macro will roll out to...

```
int foo(int a); // Forward declaration.

#define BAR()  { int a = dosomestuff(); foo(a); }

int baz() {
    int result = BAR() ? 0 : -1;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yow.  What C compiler accepts that?  gcc certainly doesn't.

Comment: @aschepler: ironically, it seems GCC is the *only* compiler that accepts it! See Michael Burr's answer.

Comment: The compiler is VisualDSP++ by Analog Devices. I will probably ask support about this tomorrow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a GCC extension to C called 'statement expressions': http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

The key thing is that a statement expression returns the last thing it does as the value of the expression:

> The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct.

In your example, that would be whatever `foo(a)` returns.

However the block must be enclosed in parens for GCC to accept the syntax.

```
int foo(); // Forward declaration.

int baz() {
    int result = ({
         int a = dosomestuff();
         foo(a);
    }) ? 0 : -1;
    return result;
}
```

I'm unaware of any other compiler that supports this.

Comment: You got there first. As an FYI here is the link to all GCC C extensions http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions

Comment: In this specific case, a more portable way to write it would probably be in order. Consider `int result = foo(dosomestuff())? 0 : -1;`

Comment: @André: definitely. The use-case for statement expressions seems to be to help create 'parameter-safe' macros or macros that iterate.  I think there's very little reason to use them in normal functions.

Comment: OK, thanks. The compiler I am using incidentally supports this aswell (just to be compatible with GCC). However, our code does not use the extra parentheses - so I assume this must be a bug in the compiler.

Comment: Indeed `BAZ` can be defined in standard C simply as `#define BAZ() foo(dosomestuff())`

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to consult your compiler documentation.  This construct is not allowed in standard C or standard C++.

It's trivial to clean this up however, e.g.

```
int baz()
{
    int result;
    {
         int a = dosomestuff();
         result = foo(a)? 0: -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know the function can be made a lot shorter.  I'm just giving an example of the minimal change necessary to make it standard-compliant.  This conversion is purely mechanical, so it can be used on ANY code that uses this construct.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a single compiler that will accept that.  Additionally, you'd be better off doing this:

```
int foo();
int dosomestuff();

int baz()
{
   int result = foo(dosomestuff()) ? 0 : -1;
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not standard C++.

In standard C++, write

```
bool baz() { return !foo( dosomestuff() ); }
```

That's it.

Comment: That changes the behavior -- the original function returned `0` or `-1`, but bool is `0` and `+1`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a non-pointer simple type, the exact value will be returned and so the return behavior is defined. That block is... really strange though, and I'm surprised there's a C compiler that won't choke on it out there.

Answer (score 0):

With C++11 you can get pretty close:

```
int foo(int a); // Forward declaration.

int baz() {
    int result = []{
         int a = dosomestuff();
         return foo(a);
    }() ? 0 : -1;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be written in standard c or c++ using the comma operator which is guaranteed to be evaluated left to right.

```
int foo(int a); // Forward declaration.

int baz() {
    int a,result = (a=dosomestuff(),foo(a)) ? 0 : -1;
    return result;
}
```

or better still

```
int baz() {
    int a;
    return (a=dosomestuff(),foo(a)) ? 0 : -1;
}
```