# How does this code work?

Tags: c++, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return value from local scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391033/return-value-from-local-scope)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int x = ({int a = 2; a;});
        printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Output: **2**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a non-standard extension to the C/C++ languages provided by GCC called [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs).  If you attempt to compile with the `-pedantic` flag, you'll get the warning "ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions".  It is **not** portable code and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I'm with Adam here.  Don't use it.  You have no idea what kind of performance it might provide, you know it's not portable, and you've just discovered that it is weird and intermittently illegible.

Comment: Saw it used in a solution in a programming contest.

Answer (score 2):

The `({ ... })` syntax is a GCC extension to the language. Think of it as a block-like expression that evaluates to the value of the last statement in the block.

Answer (score 1):

It declares a local variable called 'a', assigns it the value '2' then assigns a's value to x.